# Delete an attachement (an avatar) with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, attachment, gravatar

In my `registrations/edit.html.erb` view file I'd like to add a link to delete a current avatar (if it's attached). I've ended up with something like this:

```
<% if current_user.avatar.attached? %>
    <%= link_to "Remove avatar", { action: :remove_avatar }, method: :put %>
<% end %>
```

In custom `registrations_controller` (inherited from `Devise::RegistrationsController`) I defined a method `:remove_avatar`:

```
def remove_avatar
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    resource.avatar.purge_later
end
```

But I've got this error, which is probably caused by a lack of routes settings.

**No route matches {:action=>"remove_avatar", :controller=>"registrations", :locale=>:ru}**

What can I do to be able to link_to this method? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you would need something like this

```
put "remove_avatar", to: "registrations#remove_avatar"
```

in your routes.rb file.

Maybe it can get messier than this because of your directory structure, but it should work

Comment: I used this 
`devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' } do
  put "remove_avatar", to: "registrations#remove_avatar"
end`
and it didn't work either, unfortunatelly

Comment: You can also name a route, like: 
`put "remove_avatar", to: "registrations#remove_avatar", as: "my_remove_avatar"`, then go to rake routes and find the name of this newly created route (suppose it is devise_my_remote_avatar), so you can do `link_to "Remove avatar", devise_my_remote_avatar_path`, which will resolve directly to that route

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't even generate that particular route when the code is put between devise_for. I guess I'm doing something wrong with routes

Comment: Looks like `devise_for` doesn't accept a block. Probably  you are looking for  `devise_scope` method, which allows the `devise_scope do end` syntax